# How set a child component property to use in the parent constructor?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a base component which is extended by its children. I need to pass a property into the child component which will be used in the base component constructor.

I solved this problem with an intermediate service because I need do something in the base component constructor that I couldn't into `ngInit()`.

I tried using a string parameter in the constructor like `constructor(injector: Injector, holderName: string)` but it doesn't work.

Is there a simpler alternative to using an intermediate service?

This is my child component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.css'],
  providers: [DataService]
})
export class ChildComponent extends ParentComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(injector: Injector, childService:DataService ) { 
    childService.componentName = 'Child';
    super(injector, childService);    
    console.log('childService '+childService.componentName)   
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

This is my base component

```
@Component({
  template: ''
})
export class ParentComponent {

  private componentName: string;

  constructor(injector: Injector, @Optional() parentService:DataService = null ) {
    if (parentService !== undefined &&  parentService !== null)
    {
      this.componentName = parentService.componentName;
      console.log('parentService '+parentService.componentName);   
      //Do Something important.

    }        
  }
}

@Injectable()
export class DataService {
  componentName:string=null;
}
```

Best Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove class decorator @Component from the ParentComponent class :

```
export class ParentComponent {

  private componentName: string;
  // maybe public? idk how you plan to use it
  constructor(injector: Injector, private holderName?: string) {
    if (this.holderName)
    {
      //Do Something important.

    }        
  }
}
```

there is no relevant component inheritance, so no reason to declare it as a component.  If you want to use the unextended form as a component, then just rename is `ComponentBase` and have `ParentComponent` extend that with no holderName and all the children also extend base.